# Q: How bitset are inside?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

The question is really simple (to ask), `std::bitset<32>` is the same thing as `uint32_t` for the memory? Or it's more like `std::array<bool, 32>` ?

I usually do something like:

```
uint32_t  index : 20;
uint32_t  magic : 12;
```

So it's the same as this code ?

```
std::bitset<20>  index;
std::bitset<12>  magic;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uint32_t  index : 20;
uint32_t  magic : 12;
```

> So it's the same as this code ?

```
std::bitset<20>  index;
std::bitset<12>  magic;
```

**Absolutely not**, and it's very important that you understand the difference.

First, the internal representation of std::bitset<> is down the implementation.

With that out of the way we should examine the difference between the two code snippets above.

In c++ a *bitfield* is not a discrete object. This has important implications in multi-threaded code.

This is because c++11 and greater guarantees that unprotected access from two threads to two discrete objects is safe, but access of the same non-const object by two more more threads is a data race unless protected by a mutex.

In the above `bitset` code it would be correct to say:

thread1: `index = 10;`

thread2: `auto x = magic;`

Because they are discrete objects and therefore guaranteed not to cause data races when accessed from different threads.

In the *bitfield* code this would not be safe. The update of index would be a race with the reading of magic, and this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You're right I forget the multi-threaded implication. I know that bitfield share memory. Then if I'm going to do some multi-threaded code, I should look how the code is going to work before choose between bitset or bitfield.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel The best advice I can offer is to avoid bitfields altogether unless you are writing to memory-mapped I/O.

Comment: well I'm going to try to remove bitfield for bitset anyway. I understand why alexeykuzmin0 said yes, but you're right that's not the right answer for this question. Don't know why Stargateur was so downvote.

Answer (score 2):

A bit field need a struct

```
struct {
    uint32_t index : 20;
    uint32_t magic : 12;
}
```

so it's not the same that

```
std::bitset<20>  index;
std::bitset<12>  magic;
```

["Multiple adjacent bit fields are usually packed together (although this behavior is implementation-defined): "](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

you have two std::bitset so they can't share same memory, so it's not the same thing.

Comment: If you don't agree why you don't say why. I open to your argument.

Comment: I for one do not understand what you are trying to answer.  The question asks how `bitset` is implemented and you start comparing them to bit-fields.  No where do I see the OP asking about the difference between bit-fields and `bitset`s.

Comment: @NathanOliver he ask two question I answer the second. I am the only one who read all question ?

Comment: Ah.  I see.  That makes more sense